# How to find the Laplace transform of $f(t \pm a)$?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am trying to find the laplace transform of **$f(t \pm a)$**.
I did the integration myself and stopped at this point
$$e^{\pm as}[\int_{\pm a}^{0}e^{-sk}f(k)dk + \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sk}f(k)dk]$$
which gives rise to this term
$$e^{\pm as}[\int_{\pm a}^{0}e^{-sk}f(k)dk +F(s)]$$
Where $L[f(t)]=F(s)$ and $ t \pm a =k$
I couldn't figure out the value of this term
$$\int_{\pm a}^{0}e^{-sk}f(k)dk$$
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget the Heaviside step function, since for $t\le a \implies f(t-a)=0$
$$\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a)u(t-a)\}=\int_0^\infty f(t-a)u(t-a)e^{-st}dt$$
The Heaviside step function, changes the bound of the integral:
$$\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a)u(t-a)\}=\int_a^\infty f(t-a)e^{-st}dt$$
Substitute $t-a=u \implies du=dt$ and the bounds change ( for a not at infinity)  in the integral $t=a \implies u=0$:
$$\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a)u(t-a)\}=\int_0^\infty f(u)e^{-s(u+a)}du$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a)u(t-a)\}=e^{-as}\int_0^\infty f(u)e^{-su}du$$
Finally:
$$\boxed{\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a)u(t-a)\}=e^{-as}F(s)}$$

Comment: But why should I add the heaviside step function in the integration? I know the value of $\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a) u(t-a)\}$,I just wanted to know the value of $\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a)\}$ only without the unit step function.

Comment: So the function $\mathscr{L}\{f(t-a))\}$ can't be defined without heaviside step function?

Comment: Sorry,but still can't understand your point. Can you explain a little more in detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103655/discussion-between-hawkingo-and-isham).

Comment: I drew the [graph of $y=x^2$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/94qa9sgt6s) ,and shifted it.What do you want me to notice between 0 to a(2 in my graph)?

Comment: So why u(t) is multiplied with almost every function? Does this mean all functions are 0, in the negative domain?

Comment: Yes thtas what it means @Hawkingo

Answer (score 2):

Just use the definition.

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-ts}f(t \pm a)\ \text{d}t$$

Using $y = t\pm a$ we easily find

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-s(y \pm a)} f(y)\ \text{d}y = e^{\pm sa} \hat{f}(y)$$

This is a well known property, called frequency shifting. 
Take a look at the "properties" section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform

Comment: by using $y=  t \pm a$ wouldn't the limit of the function change to $\pm a$ ?